# TestNG, WebDriver. When I run a suite, 2nd test fails as nullPointerException

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I created two tests. Pulled up `BeforeSuite` and `AfterSuite` in superclass method.

Tests passes individually but fails when I execute them as a package.

Error `NullPointerException` at string 
    `driver.get(baseUrl + "test/test/");`

```
public class MyTestBase {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private String baseUrl;
    private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;


    @BeforeSuite
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        baseUrl = "http://test.com/";
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
    }
```

Code:

```
private void login() throws InterruptedException {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "test/test/");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input")).sendKeys("user234");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[2]/div[2]/div/input")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[2]/div[2]/div/input")).sendKeys("645637");
    submitButton();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
}
```

Test 1

```
`public class AddEquipment extends MyTestBase { }`
```

Test 2

```
`public class AddAnotherEquipment extends MyTestBase { }`
```

Both tests are the same, but with different parameters Equipment and Description fields.

I am at the beginning за learning WebDriver and tried to create something simple.

Code for test 1:

```
package com.example.tests;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class AddEquipment extends MyTestBase {

    @Test
    public void testAddEquipment() throws Exception {
        GroupData group = new GroupData("Equipment", "Description");
        createEquipment(group);
        // assert
    }

    protected void createEquipment(GroupData group) throws InterruptedException {
        login();
        menuClickEquipment();
        clickAddButton();
        fillOutForm(group);
        submitButton();
        logout();
    }

    private void login() throws InterruptedException {
        driver.get(baseUrl + "test/test/");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input")).sendKeys("user234");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[2]/div[2]/div/input")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[2]/div[2]/div/input")).sendKeys("645637");
        submitButton();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
```

Comment: Add code present inside test..

Comment: In which class do you place your test?

Comment: Also add some more code. Like class in which test are present

Comment: Use Page Object Pattern

Comment: Are both the tests in same suite?

Comment: It seems that firefox instance disappears after 1st test. How to make it live during whole suite?

Comment: @Karna Both are in the same package

Comment: @Prashanth Sams It is too difficult to me dealing PageObjectPattern, I do not know programming language. Is there any quick fix solution?

Comment: I wonder how it works when define `driver` as private in MyTestBase and use it in descendant test classes.